# Adding event listener to multiple html5 video to update progress not working

Tags: jquery, html, video, progress-bar, event-listener

I am working on a video page where multiple html5 video will be generate with PHP. Each has an unique ID. And each has it's own progress bar.

I am trying to use JQuery ***each*** method to add an ***eventListener*** ***updateProgress()*** to update the play progress bar when the video is playing. I've tried my codes with single video on the page, it works, but when I have more than one video on the page, it won't works. Hope you guys can help me out. Thanks!

```
$('video').each(function() {
    eid = this.id;
    this.addEventListener("timeUpdate"+eid, updateProgress(this, eid), false);
});

function updateProgress(vid, id) {
    var value = 0;
    if (vid.currentTime > 0) {
        value = (100 / vid.duration) * vid.currentTime;
    }

    $('#debug').html($('#debug').html()+'<br>'+'#vidProgress-'+id);
    $('#vidProgress-'+id).width(value + '%');
}
```

Here's my JSFiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/chris_poetfarmer/yoe30av2/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a function reference as teh event handler also need to declare `eid` as a local variable

```
$('video').each(function () {
    var eid = this.id;
    this.addEventListener("timeupdate", function () {
        updateProgress(this, eid)
    }, false);
});

function updateProgress(vid, id) {
    var value = 0;
    if (vid.currentTime > 0) {
        value = (100 / vid.duration) * vid.currentTime;
    }

    $('#debug').html($('#debug').html() + '<br>' + '#vidProgress-' + id);
    $('#vidProgress-' + id).width(value + '%');
}
```

---

But it can be simplified as

```
$('video').on('timeupdate', updateProgress);

function updateProgress() {
    var value = 0,
        vid = this;
    if (vid.currentTime > 0) {
        value = (100 / vid.duration) * vid.currentTime;
    }

    $('#debug').html($('#debug').html() + '<br>' + '#vidProgress-' + vid.id);
    $('#vidProgress-'+this.id).width(value + '%');
}
```